# Adding a firewalld service closes the required port instead of opening it

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, firewalld, linode

I have a fresh install of Rocky Linux 9 on a Linode Shared CPU instance. I just installed `firewalld` to get it setup. By default it has the `http` and `ssh` services enabled.

Doing an `nmap` scan at this stage shows ports 22 and 80 as open and the rest as filtered like so:

```
Host is up (0.59s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
9090/tcp closed zeus-admin
```

(I don't know what zeus admin is, i don't know if it's relevant somehow)

I currently need to open the `https` and the `smtp` ports for some of the things I'm setting up. I try to run the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
```

After that I reload the `firewalld` service through `systemctl`.

I expect port 443 to be open, but instead the nmap output shows this:

```
Host is up (0.51s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  closed https
9090/tcp closed zeus-admin
```

I get the same result for any service I try to add with the `--add-service` flag, the ports are closed. Upon testing them via URL to the service I'm setting up, I simply get `Connection refused` errors.

I also tried adding the ports directly with the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```

The results, however, are the same, the port shows as closed.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding a firewalld service closes the required port instead of opening it

That's not what "open" and "closed" mean here. Re-run nmap with `--reason` to see more.

Nmap's output is service-oriented, not firewall-oriented, and **both** "open" and "closed" indicate that there was some kind of *answer* to packets on this port – i.e. they both indicate that the firewall allowed packets through.

The difference is the kind of answer that was received: "Open" means that a TCP connection was successfully made (i.e. there is a service listening on that port) while "closed" means that the TCP handshake was explicitly refused, i.e. it *was allowed* through the firewall but there's nothing waiting for connections so a standard TCP RST was received back.

(A browser's or an HTTP client's "Connection refused" means the same thing as nmap's "closed" – it means that the server did receive your TCP handshake packet through the firewall, but actively refused it due to no service listening on that port.)

Meanwhile, if the TCP handshake packets trigger an ICMP error (such as "Administratively Prohibited") or if there's no answer whatsoever (some firewalls just drop disallowed packets outright), nmap would list the ports as **"filtered"** – in your case they're reported as "Not shown: 997 filtered ports" (nmap groups the majority-answer and only shows the exceptions).

For a more precise output specify the list of ports to scan using `-p`, as well as add `--reason` to get an additional column indicating how nmap determined the state:

```
$ nmap -p 21,22,23,24 ember
Starting Nmap 7.92 <...>

PORT   STATE    SERVICE   REASON
21/tcp filtered ftp       no-response
22/tcp open     ssh       syn-ack
23/tcp closed   telnet    conn-refused
24/tcp filtered priv-mail host-unreach

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.20 seconds
```

In this example, both ports 22 and 23 are "open" in firewall terms, but only one of them has a listening socket (the host responds with TCP ACK) while the other does not (a TCP RST is received), while ports 21 and 24 are "filtered" by the firewall.

(For illustration purposes both are filtered in different ways – port 21 has a 'drop' rule but port 24 has a 'reject with icmpx admin-prohibited' rule. Typically you would see only one or the other.)

> How can I resolve this?

Your httpd service is not listening on port 443 (e.g. the mod_ssl module hasn't been enabled, or port 443 hasn't been added to the `listen` parameter). Configure it to do so.

> (I don't know what zeus admin is, i don't know if it's relevant somehow)

I don't know what it is either, but 9090 is one of those port numbers that many services select for aesthetic reasons (like 8888 or 5555 or 8080) regardless of what it was officially assigned to, so 99.99% of the time it has nothing to do with the original "zeus-admin" listing.

Of course, Nmap doesn't really know whether the server meant to use that port for zeus-admin or not (especially if the port is 'closed' and there *is* no service that could be probed further), so it just reports the name from its "nmap-services" database.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Now that I know the ports aren't the issue, I managed to troubleshoot the problem and found the problem was in my configs.